# Trying to add a playerbot

Tags: azerothcore

I am trying to create the possibility to add an offline character as a player-bot.
My first attempt was to insert a new record into creature_template using SQL and then load the creature.

```
Creature* creature = new Creature();
creature->Create(...)
creature->SaveToDB(...)
sObjectMgr->AddCreatureToGrid(...)
```

This worked only after restarting the worldserver.
My second attempt was to pre-create a few entries in creature_template table.
This worked well, but I was not able to change the name at all.

Now, on my third attempt I create a CreatureTemplate instance, fill it up with data (name, subname, etc) and add it to the cache

```
_creatureTemplateStoreFast.insert(_creatureTemplateStoreFast.begin() + temp->Entry, temp);
```

Works fine, but the names and subnames are not correct at all ingame.
Sometimes the name of the char is "Warrior Human Male" for example, which I used on attempt 2. Then other names appear, which I used before.

At the moment I definitely set names like.

```
CreatureTemplate* temp = new CreatureTemplate();
temp->Entry = entry;
temp->Modelid1 = 3343;
temp->Name = name;
temp->SubName = "Bot";
```

I also deleted all rows from creature_template and creatures which I added before.

I already tried Eluna and gave up because Unit::SetName() was not working.

Now my questions.
Is there any other table that holds the name and subname of the creature?
Am I going the right way to spawn a player bot at all?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the names I found out already.
If someone has a similar problem, here is the solution:
Delete the directory with the name "Cache" on your client.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your first question; however, I will be attempting to make one or more bots. but by directly accessing and creating accounts/characters through sql.

When the character needs to move to a quest, the bot will access the quest start location (end location if reqiired) and what other things need to be collected along the way.

Then the character moves at the same rate as we would by direct update to the database, I'm hoping the bot will appear in game this way.

Alternatively, a bot to grind to final level, auction house as it goes, buying / selling / crafting.

Alternatively, maybe it'll be easier to create a separate bot fit for purpose pvp / pve / auction.

I want to figure out what the most efficient way will be.

Apologies for waffling!